# How big of a Artificial Magnetic Field would be needed for Mars to be shielded at L1?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, space

I was recently reading an awesome [Paper](https://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/V2050/pdf/8250.pdf) that details a possible process for restarting the Martian atmosphere. The paper explains that a *Sufficiently Sized* artificial magnetic dipole of 1 to 2 Tesla at the L1 Lagragian Point could effectively shield Mars from Solar Wind, allowing the Atmosphere to regenerate without constant Solar-Wind ejection.

However, the manuscript never clarifies what "Sufficiently Sized" means, only detailing the strength: 1 - 2T. I assume its magnetic field has to occlude the planet.

[image]

Assuming it's a solenoid of some sort, how large would the solenoid need to be to sufficiently protect the Martian Atmosphere?

Some Related Questions:

[1. How would it be possible to kick start Mars's magnetic field?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2423/how-would-it-be-possible-to-kick-start-marss-magnetic-field)

[2. How strong a magnetic field would be needed to deflect cosmic rays?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/214771/how-strong-a-magnetic-field-would-be-needed-to-deflect-cosmic-rays)

Comment: I'm kind of skeptical that this has been thought out carefully.  The article you've linked is a conference proceeding, which is not peer-reviewed;  and the only support it gives for its "1–2 T" claim is a link to [this article,](https://room.eu.com/article/our-changing-world-and-the-mounting-risk-of-a-calamitous-solar-storm) also in an unreviewed publication, which does not present any details of the scheme beyond the very broadest concepts.